# "Select parent set of selected items to change to"...?

Tags: grammar, phrasing

I am writing a program where each item has a "parent set" attribute.

I am trying to create a function that changes the "parent set" value of selected items, and am having troubles trying to phrase **two** particular messages in the user prompts.

Currently for these two messages I came up with :

1. "Select quantity of items whose parent sets are to be changed".
2. "Select parent set of selected items to change to".

both of which sound extremely awkward and confusing.

Although English has always been my first language, I am starting to get a headache and a serious brainfart over how to phrase these messages properly. I truly appreciate any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make it [wizard style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wizard_(software)) and set a headline along the lines of "Change Parent" so that is clear what the overall purpose of the wizard is.

The first panel would say "Select items".

The second panel would say "Select parent for items".

I hope this provides a headache-preventing clue to your dilemma. :)

Comment: Hi Michael, this certainly sounds better, thank you for the reply! :) Since these messages are part of an overall workflow, I have decided to replace "Change parent set" to "Move to parent set" to better reflect that the user is actually initiating an action rather than just changing some particular value. With the latter phrase, it become easier the phrase as I originally intended and it is possible to incorporate your suggestion as well.